# couldn't upgrade to fedora due to error "nothing provides python3.8dist(python-magic)"

Tags: python, fedora, python3

I'm using fedora 32. I did `sudo dnf update -y`

I got below error -

```
    $ sudo dnf update -y
    Last metadata expiration check: 1:24:24 ago on Mon 30 Nov 2020 04:42:35 PM EST.
    Dependencies resolved.

    Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package lutris-0.5.7.1-1.fc32.x86_64
    - nothing provides python3.8dist(python-magic) needed by lutris-0.5.8-1.fc32.x86_64
    =================================================================================================
    Package             Architecture        Version                      Repository            Size
    =================================================================================================
    Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
    lutris              x86_64              0.5.8-1.fc32                 updates              819 k

    Transaction Summary
    =================================================================================================
    Skip  1 Package

    Nothing to do.
    Complete!
```

I tried to install that package again -

```
    $ sudo dnf install PackageKit-glib
    Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:10 ago on Tue 01 Dec 2020 02:42:17 AM EST.
    Package PackageKit-glib-1.1.13-3.fc32.x86_64 is already installed.
    Package PackageKit-glib-1.1.13-3.fc32.i686 is already installed.
    Dependencies resolved.
    Nothing to do.
    Complete!
```

My operating system details are

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 32 (Thirty Two)
Release:        32
Codename:       ThirtyTwo
```

Below are the dteails about python version in my system -

```
    $ which python
    /usr/bin/python
    $ which python3
    /usr/bin/python3
    $ python --version
    Python 3.8.6
    $ python3 --version
    Python 3.8.6
```

How can I fix this above issue?

Comment: What is the result of `which python`?

Comment: @Anaksunaman - updated the details about python/python3 inside the post. please let me know if you need any other details.

Answer (score 1):

I did `sudo dnf remove PackageKit-glib -y` and then the upgrade

Comment: I have no idea why that would help, and it didn't fix the same problem for me.

Comment: @mikrbabcock may be this will help https://serverfault.com/a/1045307/390307

Comment: it does not; as per that link, it appears to be a bug others are also dealing with.